# Apexchart option updates not working under vue3

Tags: vuejs3, apexcharts

I'm building a multiple series line chart using Apexcharts under Vue3, and running into an issue where chart options are not being updated. The series data updates as expected, but I have yet to see an option update successfully.

I'm using composition api with ref, which overall seems to be working great. But once the chart is assigned via `lineChart.value = achart`, no changes I make will update the chart. For example, the options file contains `colors: ['#FFFF00', '#0000FF']`, which is yellow and blue, but updating the ref with new colors changes nothing on the chart. Looking at the data using moustache syntax, I can see the new color values have been updated, but not in the chart. See attached screenshot.

[image]

I have followed every guide and post I can find, but still no luck. Does anyone know if this is a common issue, or if there is some special consideration I should be taking? If this is a larger issue I'll work on creating a codepen project.
Thanks

UPDATE: Adding a [codesandbox.io project](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-apexcharts-update-issue-0ve6t)

Answer (score 3):

I encounter the same problem, since I use async and await the data updates after a seconds but doesnt update the chart itself,
I read the docs and it said that you need to update the whole value of the chart options.

```
chartOptions.value.xaxis.categories = [2020, 2021, 2022]
```

instead

```
chartOptions.value = { 
 ... charts: {}
     xaxis: {
          ...
         categories: [2022, 2021, 2022]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `updateOptions` insted https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#updateOptions

```
ApexCharts.exec("chartID", "updateOptions", {
        series: [
          {
            data: [1,2,3,2]
          }
        ],
        xaxis: {
          categories: ['a', 'b', 'c','d'],
        },
        colors:['#00ff00']
      })
```

Comment: I've been looking into it, but being new to Vue3 I'm not sure where the ApexCharts variable is coming from. I see how it is created in a non-reactive environment, is there a similar method to execute this function from within Vue3?

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/6m892V1R I'm not sure how you do this right now but this code worked for me. Note: with `updateOptions` you will have animation when series changes

Comment: This looks to be different than the vue3 api I'm using, but I'll see what I can translate to my project. thanks!